# detecting blurred rectangles on multimodal grayscaleimage

Tags: image-processing, opencv, feature-detection

I have the following image [image: rectangle pattern board]

I'm trying to find the pixel coordinates of main rectangles (those between white lines). I tried few things but I can't obtain good enough solution. The solution doesn't have to be perfect and it's ok if not all rectangles are detected (especially those really small ones). Though corners location will have to be as much exact as possible, especially with those bigger blurry (I'm trying to write some simple AR engine).

I can clarify there are only 4 levels of grayscale: 0, 110, 180 and 255 (when printing, no screen it will vary because of lightning and shadows)

So far I tried few things:

1. manual multilevel thresholding (because of shadows and different lightning it didn't work)
2. adaptive thresholding : 2 problems:

   - it combines 180 and 255 colors into white, and 0, 110 into black
   - edge/corner location of blurred(bigger) rectangles is not exact (it adds blur to rectangle area)
3. sobel edge detection (corners of blurred rectangles are more sharp, but it detects also inner edges in rectangles, also those edge contours are not always closed

Looks like combining those two thinks somehow would yield better results. Or maybe somebody have different idea?

I was also thinking about doing floodfill, but it was hard to find for sure good seed point and threshold automatically (there might be some other white objects in the background). Besides I will want to optimize later this for GPU and floodfill algorithm is rather not a good fit for this.

Below is some sample code I tried so far:

```
image = cv2.imread('data/image.jpg');
gray  = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('image', gray) 


adaptive = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 601, 0)
cv2.imshow('adaptive', adaptive)


gradx = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=3)
grady = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=3)
abs_gradx = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grady)
abs_grady = cv2.convertScaleAbs(grady)
grad = cv2.addWeighted(abs_gradx, 0.5, abs_grady, 0.5, 0)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(5,5))
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(grad, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
grad = cv2.morphologyEx(grad, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imshow('sobel',grad)


#kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(7,7))
#grad = cv2.morphologyEx(grad, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
retval, grad = cv2.threshold(grad, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('sobel+morph+thrs',grad)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Have you considered corner detection?

Comment: yes I tried goodFeaturesToTrack and there where to many false-possitives

Comment: Just to clarify the goal.  You have large white strips outlining squares, which are full of rectangles(some of which are squares as well).  Do you want the corners of the large squares, the corners of the small rectangles filling the squares or both?

Comment: @Januxx clarying: there were false-possitives with blurry one. Besides I with corners detection it was difficult to later figure out to which this corner belong to (creating contours) and estimate how many corners it should detect.

Hammer: corners of the large squares are enough (but having the small ones as well is ok too). And not only global list of all corners but knowing that 'those 4 corners belong to some one rectangle' - this means with corners detection I guess its difficult to later apply findContours

Comment: +1 for good question.  It would be great if you could show some of your result images as well, so people wouldn't have to compile and run the code to understand the problem.

Comment: +1: Great question, although perhaps it would be better suited on dsp.stackexchange.com which is more suited to algorithms, while SO is more for programming difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your answer lies in using the Hough transform to detect lines, extending these lines to span the breaks between the darker squares, and then looking for intersects marking out corners. I've had a quick play in Matlab and have come up with the following, it's not perfect but should show the potential:

```
% Open image
i = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwcXm.jpg');

% Use a sharpening filter to enhance some of the edges
H = fspecial('unsharp');
i = imfilter(i, H, 'replicate');
% Detect edge segments using canny
BW = edge(i, 'canny');

% Apply hough transform to edges
[H, T, R] = hough(BW, 'RhoResolution', 0.5, 'Theta', -90:0.5:89.5);
% Find peaks in hough transform
P = houghpeaks(H, 5, 'threshold', ceil(0.1*max(H(:))));
% Extract lines from peaks, extending partial lines
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P, 'FillGap', 100, 'MinLength', 5);

% Plot detected lines on image
imshow(i); hold on;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
end
```

With the final result:

[image: Final Result]

Obviously there's room for improvement, with a number of lines still to detect, but if tweaking the various parameters doesn't work you could take the initial result and the search for more lines with similar angles to obtain a more complete set. The corners can then be found from the intersects which should be simple enough to extract.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

- [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect all straight lines
- Look for sets of parallel lines that are:

  - A sufficient distance apart
  - Separated by the lighter color

There are a couple of things that make your problem trickier than it needs to be:

- Perspective distortion
- Changes in lighting, minor shadows

If you could minimize the above, it may help solving the problem.